# How to sort JSONArray of JSONObject which contain another JSONObject?

Tags: java, json, sorting

I am able to sort JSONArray of JSONObject but I stuck when I need to sort array like follows:

```
[{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": {
        "key4": "value4",
        "key5": "value5"
    }
}, {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": {
        "key4": "value4",
        "key5": "value5"
    }
}]
```

I want to sort this array on "Key4".

Here is my code while sorting on key1

```
public static JSONArray sortJsonArray(JSONArray array, final String key) throws JSONException 
{
        List<JSONObject> jsons = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            jsons.add(array.getJSONObject(i));
        }
        Collections.sort(jsons, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(JSONObject lhs, JSONObject rhs) {
                String lid = null;
                String rid = null;
                try {
                    lid = lhs.getString(key);
                    rid = rhs.getString(key);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Here you could parse string id to integer and then compare.
                return lid.compareTo(rid);
            }
        });
        return new JSONArray(jsons);
    }
```

Comment: As far as I know, JSONArray is not a sortable data-structure, you'd need to put the JSONObjects into a `List<JSONObject>` then sort

Comment: Right, I put that but I can sort only on Key1 or key2; How I can sort that on key4?

Comment: @cricket_007: I added my code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare `lhs.getJSONObject("key3").getString("key4")` to `rhs.getJSONObject("key3").getString("key4")`.

Answer (score 0):

Just pasting my code Here(As per @cricket_007 Helps), May this help some others:

```
public static JSONArray sortJsonArrayOpenDate(JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
        List<JSONObject> jsons = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            jsons.add(array.getJSONObject(i));
        }
        Collections.sort(jsons, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(JSONObject lhs, JSONObject rhs) {
                String lid = null;
                String rid = null;
                try {
                    lid = lhs.getJSONObject("key3").getString("key4");
                    rid = rhs.getJSONObject("key3").getString("key4");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return lid.compareTo(rid);
            }
        });
        return new JSONArray(jsons);
    }
```